# Can i attach an iframe element to a Leaftlet tooltip?

Tags: iframe, leaflet, tooltip

I am trying to show a World bank interactive chart in a tooltip, attached to a polygon in leaflet.

The chart comes as an iframe element and looks like this:

```
<iframe src="https://data.worldbank.org/share/widget?indicators=IS.SHP.GOOD.TU&locations=SA" width='450' height='300' frameBorder='0' scrolling="no" ></iframe>
```

I have defined the polygon and using the `.bindToolTip('')` to display content when mouse is over.

However, every time i insert the iframe element leaflet returns an error?

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: You say "Leaflet returns an error". What error?

Comment: Could you add details of the error?